# Espacio apuntado con malloc() no se libera con free()

Tags: c

En el siguiente código; en el loop el valor de ncrC->count varía debido a que el pointer s no se reinicia al utilizr free(s) y no localiza como es debido al hacer el loop el string: "Counter = ". Por favor ayuda.

```html
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXUSE 1000
#define TAGSIZE 4
#define MAXBUF 100

struct ncrcode                                 /* Structure of ncrcode  */
{
    int count;
                                
};


int main()
{
    int q = 1, i = 0, x=0, a=0;
    char ch;
    
    FILE * fp;
    
    struct ncrcode *ncrC;
    
    ncrC = (struct ncrcode *) malloc(sizeof(*ncrC));    /* gets room for the new node */
    
    
    while (q)
    {
        /* This .txt file contains a file reference to another file */
        fp = fopen("nd0_1.txt", "r");
        
        char *s = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*20);
        
        /* 1 - Get COUNTER getnodecounter() */
        
        while( (ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
        {
            s[i++] = ch;
            
            if (strcmp(s,"Counter = ") == 0)
            {
                printf("\nPLAKAPLAKA%d", a++);
                break;
            }
        }
        i = 0;
        printf("\n First\n%d\n",ncrC->count = 0);
        while( (ch = fgetc(fp)) != '\n')
        {
            printf("%c\n", ch);
            ncrC->count = (ch - 48) + ( ncrC->count * 10);
        }
        
        printf("\n STRINNNN \n%d\n",ncrC->count);
        
        free(s);
        fclose(fp);
    }
    return (0);
```

Comment: ¿Qué te hace decir que la memoria de `s` no se libera? ¿Qué es lo que has notado?

Comment: Muchas gracias @SJuan76, el error consiste en que *s permanece apuntando al string "Counter = " y al realizar el segundo loop encuentra la palabra tras recoger la primera letra del archivo .txt y altera así el valor final de ncrC->counter. He añadido la opción de igualar s a NULL (s = NULL) pero no funciona cuando lo hago después de liberar s free(s);.
No obstante, cuando le asigno NULL al puntero después  de free() no funciona, sí lo hace cuando lo asigno antes. ¿ Ves algún problema en esto?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`free()` está liberando correctamente la memoria.<sup>1</sup>

Lo que no te cuadra es que `malloc`, al asignar la memoria, **no la inicializa**. Te da un puntero a memoria y la "basura" que haya allí se mantiene.

En tu caso parece ser que el gestor de memoria libera `s` y, al volver a pedirle la misma cantidad de memoria, te vuelve a dar la misma posición (que ahora está disponible)<sup>2</sup>. Si no te liberara la memoria, `malloc` te devolvería *un puntero a cualquier otra zona*, y no a la misma.

El verdadero problema está al leer el fichero. Tú código va carácter a carácter asignando al array, pero el problema es que al acabar de leer los caracteres no le pones el valor de terminación de `string` (`\0`). Por eso, cualquier funcion de strings (`strcmp`, `strcpy`, etc.) seguirá leyendo más allá de los caracteres que has asignado hasta encontrar un `\0`.

Solución. Dos opciones:

- La correcta para este caso es que, despues de leer del fichero, asignes `\0` para terminar el `string`. Viendo tu código, haría:

  ```
  s[i++] = ch;
  s[i] = (char) 0;  // En cada iteración "terminas" la cadena para poder
                    // usar strcmp. Si iteras otra vez, el 0 se sobreescribirá
                    // con el siguiente caracter.
  if (strcmp....
  ```
- Ya más relacionada con la gestión de memoria, puedes llamar a `calloc` en vez de a `malloc`; lo que hace es que aparte de asignarte la memoria te la inicializa toda a `0`.

También hay que notar que estar continuamente solicitando y libernado memoria es muy poco eficiente. Si no mantienes una referencia permanente a la memoria, sería mucho mejor hacer el `malloc` antes de iniciar el bucle y liberarlo después. Mientras te acuerdes de poner el `\0` para finalizar el `string`, no habrá problema con reusar la misma zona. Naturalmente, una vez hagas hecho, solo podrás aplicar la primera solución.

---

<sup>1</sup>Una prueba sencillita. Aunque liberar un puntero dos veces significa "comportamiento indefinido" y en teoría puede pasar cualquier cosa, en mi experiencia casi siempre significa una terminación abrupta del programa. Puedes hacer el experimento de liberar dos veces `s` y comprobar que, posiblemente, el programa sufra una crash.

<sup>2</sup>Hasta donde yo sé, `malloc` es libre de devolverte un puntero cualquiera; que te devuelva el mismo depende de la implementación.

Comment: Buenísima respuesta, muchísimas gracias. Me lo he leído un par de veces y creo que entiendo todo.